# Can I grow callisia repens turtle vine inside the house?

Tags: houseplants, shade

Can I grow [callisia repens](https://garden.org/plants/view/87910/Turtle-Vine-Callisia-repens/), turtle vine, in the house without any sunlight, only in shade?

Thanks.

Comment: Bamboo is right. The link I added lists it as being able to grow inside in many types of light, including partial or complete shade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have planted it inside my house. Let us see how it grows.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. An update in the future would be great. I hope it stays healthy and grows well!

Answer (score 6):

Should be fine - needs warmth and good daylight, but not having any sun as a houseplant is fine, even outdoors it prefers dappled sunlight or partial shade, see here https://www.gardenseeker.com/indoor-plants/callisia_repens.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have planted it inside my house and it has been more than one month now it is still green. Let us see in further days also if it grows.